# understanding javascript variable handling and referening especially canvas ImageArray and array assigning

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

consider this code:

```
var deSaturated = deSaturate(greyscaleCtx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
```

imageData comes from getImageData canvas function.

```
function deSaturate (imageData) {
                var theData = imageData.data;

                var dataLength = theData.length;
                var i = dataLength-1;
                var lightLevel;
                // Iterate through each pixel, desaturating it
                while ( i >= 0) {
                    // To find the desaturated value, average the brightness of the red, green, and blue values

                    theData[i] = theData[i+1] = theData[i+2] = (theData[i] + theData[i + 1] + theData[i + 2]) / 3;

                    // Fully opaque
                    theData[i+3] = 255;
                    // returning an average intensity of all pixels.  Used for calibrating sensitivity based on room light level.
                    lightLevel += theData[i]; //combining the light level in the samefunction
                    i -= 4;

                }

                imageData.data = theData; //bring back theData into imageData.data - do I really need this?


                var r = [lightLevel/dataLength,imageData]
                return r;
            }
```

during the writing and optimizing of this code I found out I don't really understand how js   is treating for example "theData" variable. is working with it just a short way to reference imageData.data in which case I don't need the following code in the end:

```
imageData.data = theData
```

but then do I pay in degraded performance ( a lot of  DOM I/O)?

or is doing `theData = imageData.data` actually copying the original array (represented as Uint8ClampedArray) and then I have to reassign the modified data to `imageData.data`.

I guess this is basic javascript, but I found contradictory code examples in MDN and other developer resources and I would really like to understand this properly.

thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't think the `imageData.data = theData` line is necessary.

Comment: @IanKuca: Nope, it's not. It seems to be a pretty clear and obvious alias for imageData.data (7chars vs 14 chars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran a quick test:

```
    var idata = ctx.getImageData(0,0,300,300);
    var data = idata.data;
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        data[i]=0;
    }

    ctx.putImageData(idata,0,0);
```

And that properly blanks out part of the screen as expected. However without putImageData nothing will happen. So changing the data object, whether stored in a different variable or not, *will* be reflected in that imageData object. However this will not affect the canvas until putImageData has been called.

So, yes, you can remove that final assignment and it will work as desired.

However I will warn that it is *not* a valid assumption that it is a Uint8ClampedArray. Yes, that is how Chrome handles it (last I checked), and it is indeed what the official specification uses. However some browsers have no notion of Uint8ClampedArray, while still supporting canvas through the now deprecated CanvasPixelArray.

So all you are guaranteed to get is something with the some array-like interface. I had to learn this the hard way when I tried to cache interesting features of image data by creating a new Uint8ClampedArray, which failed in some browsers.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CanvasPixelArray

Comment: thanks! just another small thing - since I don't neet the picture to change, I just use the array to compute motion in video drawn to canvas. I get another picture(frame actually) in 60 fps or something like that.  is putImageData still needed? if I only use the imageData and not recovering more information from the canvas?

Comment: Yeah if you don't care about updating the canvas itself there's no need to putImageData.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, assigning either an `array` or an `object` just assigns a reference to that array or object - it does not make a copy of the data.  A copy is only made if you physically create a new array and copy the data over or call some function that is designed to do that for you.

So, if `imageData.data` is an `array`, then assigning it to `theData` just makes a shortcut for referring to the same data.  It does not make a new copy of the data.  Thus, after modifying the data pointed to by `theData`, you don't have to assign it back to `imageData.data` because there is only one copy of the data and both `theData` and `imageData.data` point already point to that same copy of the data.

So, in direct answer to your question, this line is unnecessary:

```
imageData.data = theData;
```

Comment: Yet [`imageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/ImageData) is a host object which might have a getter and setter instead of a simple property, and `theData` is not a normal `Array` but an [`CanvasPixelArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CanvasPixelArray) which is quite like a typed array. So I think this needs some more investigation

Comment: It does not. The `data` property is even read-only so the line is totally useless: http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#imagedata